# Disable automatic screen lock in iOS 5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5.1

The following line of code prevents the app from automatically locking the screen after some idle time.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES; //write this in applicationDidFinishLaunching
```

It works well till iOS 5.0.
But iOS 5.1 does not respect this line and locks the screen after some idle time.
How to solve this irritating issue?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The same code works fine when its installed in 5.0.1 device. But I dont know why it is not working with 5.1 device.

Comment: that sounds like a bug. If you like to report bugs -> http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: Where are you calling this code? Are you sure it is being executed (have you set a breakpoint and checked)? Apple's example is to put `application.idleTimerDisabled = YES;` in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` of the delegate

Comment: Yes @NickBull i had put the code inside applicationDidFinishLaunching only. But as you can see, the same code works fine when its installed in 5.0.1 device.

Comment: You should be using `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: My bad. I was actually using `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` only. I should'nt have confused.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I filed a bug report to apple...

Comment: Have you tried taking one of Apple's example applications and built and run that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just setting `[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;` in

```
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
```

works well for me. However, there is a caveat. I have noticed that every time I invoke camera utility to take a snapshot, **idleTimerDisable** gets set to **NO** behind the scene. So right after I upload my image, I had to call the following line of code again:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

I would not be surprised if there are more places throughout that require same strategy. So far this approach has worked without issues for me.

Comment: I don't really need idleTimerDisabled = YES in the whole app. You can just set up [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES]; where you code need it and turn the property off when is no more necessary with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: NO];

Answer (score 25):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```

worked for me on iOS 5.1

Answer (score 5):

No there *should* be no difference. Perhaps you have another mistake.. 
See [iOS 5.0 to 5.1 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS51APIDiffs/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011328)

Answer (score 3):

> **Important:** You should set this property only if necessary and should be sure to reset it to NO when the need no longer exists. Most
>   applications should let the system turn off the screen when the idle
>   timer elapses. This includes audio applications. With appropriate use
>   of Audio Session Services, playback and recording proceed
>   uninterrupted when the screen turns off. The only applications that
>   should disable the idle timer are mapping applications, games, or
>   similar programs with sporadic user interaction.

Maybe You exceeds the allowable time limit of being awake?

Comment: My application is definitely one with sporadic user interaction ;) but see the code is working in 5.0.1 without any issue. That strikes odd.

Answer (score 1):

i know its is old, but i found this good and in Swift you can do it look a like this

`application.idleTimerDisabled = true`

Thanks for you answers! i use right now xcode 7 Beta 3 ( Swift 2 )

Comment: Swift 3: `application.isIdleTimerDisabled = true`

Answer (score 1):

For Swift, I use this to do outside of delegate:

```
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if your application is registered for some background task, for example GPS location updating.